# Printing struct pointers from one instance of the struct

Tags: c, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

typedef struct{
    int* first;
    int* second;
    int* third;
}Arrays;

Arrays generate_arrays(int len);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int len=10;
    Arrays array;
    array=generate_arrays(len);
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {

        printf("%d %d %d\n",*array.first++,*array.second++,*array.third++);
    }

    return 0;
}
Arrays generate_arrays(int len)

{
int i;
Arrays array;
int a[len],b[len],c[len];

for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{

    a[i]=((rand()%len)+1);
    b[i]=((rand()%len)+1);
    c[i]=((rand()%len)+1);

}


array.first=a;
array.second=b;
array.third=c;

printf("\n\n");
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{

    printf("%d %d %d\n",*array.first++,*array.second++,*array.third++);
}
return array;
}
```

In the code above I am trying to print out the struct values of just one instance of the struct Arrays, instead of using a pointer. To do that I am using arrays to store the random numbers and then assigning an array to a pointer inside the struct. The printf inside the function prints out the ints normally(top set of numbers), however when the printf in main runs it prints out garbage(bottom set of numbers). Sample output is below. So my question is why would it be doing this because the printfs are the exact same?

```
8 10 4
9 1 3
5 9 4
10 1 6
3 3 8
4 8 10
1 3 4
10 10 8
1 4 10
9 7 6

-65536 0 0
8064 0 0
-64641 0 1606415984
-65536 0 32767
-1 0 2058584832
0 0 32767
0 -64641 1606416144
0 -65536 32767
-65536 -1 -1857669479
8064 0 32767
```

Comment: `a`, `b`, and `c` are out of scope after the call to `generate_arrays` and using them by address is undefined behavior.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` is in the wrong place - it should be *before* `array=generate_arrays(len);` which @iharob updated answer has.

Comment: @WeatherVane good catch, I didn't notice that until you said something. Thanks.

Comment: While debugging it can be helpful to use `srand(0)` so the sequence (and errors!) are repeatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the addresses of local variables in the struct members.

The `a` `b` and `c` arrays are local to the `generate_arrays()` function and when that function returns the arrays are deallocated.

You need to ensure that they data will still be valid after the function returns, so I would suggest the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct{
    int *first;
    int *second;
    int *third;
}Arrays;

Arrays generate_arrays(int len);

int main(void)
{
    int    index;
    int    length;
    Arrays array;

    srand(time(NULL));

    length = 10;
    array  = generate_arrays(length);

    for (index = 0 ; index < length ; index++)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", array.first[index], array.second[index], array.third[index]);

    free(array.first);
    free(array.second);
    free(array.third);

    return 0;
}

Arrays generate_arrays(int length)
{
    int    index;
    Arrays array;

    array.first  = malloc(length * (sizeof(*array.first)));
    array.second = malloc(length * (sizeof(*array.first)));
    array.third  = malloc(length * (sizeof(*array.first)));

    if ((array.first == NULL) || (array.second == NULL) || (array.third == NULL))
     {
        free(array.first);
        free(array.second);
        free(array.third);

        array.first  = NULL;
        array.second = NULL;
        array.third  = NULL;

        return array;
     }

    for (index = 0 ; index < length ; index++)
    {
        array.first[index]  = ((rand() % length) + 1);
        array.second[index] = ((rand() % length) + 1);
        array.third[index]  = ((rand() % length) + 1);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration

```
int a[len],b[len],c[len];
```

is declaring/allocating variables which are local to the function.

You should perform something like this:

```
int *a = malloc(len * sizeof(int)), 
    *b = malloc(len * sizeof(int)), 
    *c = malloc(len * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Question is C, not C++.

Comment: Yes just in C, so I couldn't use that.

Comment: it doesn't mean it's not helpful, and it does not deserve a downvote.... I updated the answer in order to replace `new` with `malloc`, it's the only difference!